# Thread and sum of bidimensional matrix

Tags: multithreading, matrix, terminal, sum, row

I have to calculate the sum of the elements in a bidimensional matrix, using a separate thread to calculate the sum of each row. Then the main thread adds up these sums printing the final result.
Can you guys see what's wrong?
(I'm all new to the threads stuff)

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void sumR(void* _a,int m,int n,int sum)
{
       int i;
        int (*a)[m]=_a;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                sum+=a[n][i];
}
int main()
{
        int a[20][20],sum1,sum;
        int m=3,n=3,k=3,i,j;
        for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
        {
                k=k+3;
                for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
                        a[i][j]=k;
        }
        sum1=0;
        for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
        {
                sum=0;
                pthread_t th;
                pthread_create(&th,NULL,&sumR,&a,&m,&n,&sum);
                sum1+=sum;
                pthread_join(&th,NULL);
        }
        printf("Sum of the matrix is: %d",sum1);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I see is that your loop does essentially this:

```
for each row
    start thread
    add thread's sum to total
    wait for thread to exit
```

That's not going to work because you're adding the thread's sum before the thread is done calculating it. You need to wait for the thread to finish:

```
start thread
wait for thread to exit
add thread's sum to total
```

However, that model doesn't take advantage of multiple threads. You only have one thread running at a time.

What you need to do is create all of the threads and store them in an array. Then wait for each thread to exit and add its sum to the total. Something like:

```
for i = 0 to num_threads-1
    threads[i] = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &sums[i], ...)
```

And then

```
for i = 0 to num_threads-1
    pthread_join(&threads[i], ...);
    sum += sums[i];
```

That way, all of your threads are running at the same time, and you harvest the result only when the thread is done.